# Are callbacks for requests a bad practice in node.js?

Tags: node.js, request, pipe

Imagine you want to download an image or a file, this would be the first way the internet will teach you to go ahead:

```
request(url, function(err, res, body) {
    fs.writeFile(filename, body);
});
```

But doesn't this accumulate all data in `body`, filling the memory?
Would a `pipe` be totally more efficient?

```
request(url).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename));
```

Or is this handled internally in a similar matter, buffering the stream anyway, making this irrelevant?

Furthermore, if I want to use the callback but *not* the `body` (because you can still  `pipe`), will this memory buffer still be filled?

I am asking because the first (callback) method allows me to chain downloads in stead of launching them in parallel(*), but I don't want to fill a buffer I'm not gonna use either. So I need the callback if I don't want to resort to something fancy like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) just to use [queue](https://github.com/caolan/async#queue) to prevent this.

(*) Which is bad because if you just `request` too many files before they are complete, the async nature of `request` will cause node to choke to death in an overdose of events and memory loss. First you'll get these:

```
"possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit."
```

And when stretching it, 500 piped requests will fill your memory up and crash node. That's why you need the callback in stead of the pipe, so you know when to start the next file.

Comment: Pipe would be more efficient as it will stream the data to the `WriteStream` as data is available. I don't think your last statement is true though.

Comment: It seems like it is. Try downloading 50 documents. You will get _"possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit."_ Download 500 and your memory will fill up and crash node. That's why you need the callback in stead of the pipe, so you know when to start the next file.

Comment: Resandro, I think you are confusing streaming, callbacks, and flow control. It is flow control that will properly maintain limits of outgoing connecttions (see async.queue, async.eachLimit, etc), but in both a callback/buffering paradigm and a streaming paradigm, you need flow control and resource management. These topics are distinct.

Answer (score 3):

> But doesn't this accumulate all data in body, filling the memory?

Yes, many operations such as your first snippet buffer data into memory for processing. Yes this uses memory, but it is at least convenient and sometimes required depending on how you intend to process that data. If you want to load an HTTP response and parse the body as JSON, that is almost always done via buffering, although it's possible with a streaming parser, it is much more complicated and usually unnecessary. Most JSON data is not sufficiently large such that streaming is a big win.

> Or is this handled internally in a similar matter, making this irrelevant?

No, APIs that provide you an entire piece of data as a string use buffering and not streaming.

However, multimedia data, yes, you cannot realistically buffer it to memory and thus streaming is more appropriate. Also that data tends to be opaque (you don't parse it or process it), which is also good for streaming.

Streaming is nice when circumstances permit it, but that doesn't mean there's anything necessarily wrong with buffering. The truth is buffering is how the vast majority of things work most of the time. In the big picture, streaming is just buffering 1 chunk at a time and capping them at some size limit that is well within the available resources. Some portion of the data needs to go through memory at some point if you are going to process it.

> Because if you just request too many files one by one, the async nature of request will cause node to choke to death in an overdose of events and memory loss.

Not sure exactly what you are stating/asking here, but yes, writing effective programs requires thinking about resources and efficiency.

See also [substack's rant on streaming/pooling in the hyperquest README](https://github.com/substack/hyperquest).

Comment: You started out good, but -1 for your demeaning tone and open door examples. If you could remove your frustrations about this question and the obvious buffering limitation statements, and provide something useful instead, I'll remove the downvote.

Comment: Better, although I didn't mind the hipster points. The final quote about the node choke isn't actually a question, it's the reason why I asked the previous question: _"if I want to use the callback but don't use the body (because you can still pipe), will this (buffered) memory still be used (wasted)?"_ 'Cause I need the callback if I don't want to resort to something fancy like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) just to use [queue](https://github.com/caolan/async#queue) to prevent this. I think the answer is yes tho, so I'm looking for an alternative.

Comment: You are missing the point that whether you stream the response or buffer them doesn't affect how many concurrent requests you have pending. What you want to do is understand when you have "enough" pending requests and the WAIT before issuing more. It's about controlling how much I/O you start, not whether you buffer or stream the responses.

Comment: For example, you could use even a simple integer keeping track of how many requests are active and when that hits a threshold, don't start any new ones until it dips back under the threshold. Possible in both buffered and streamed APIs. Or you could use `async.queue` which does essentially that.

Comment: Well you seem to misunderstand me, as I already indicated I want to have one pending request at a time, and launch the next one once the previous one is finished. That's why I need the callback, but _not_ the buffering. `async.queue` is a solution I proposed myself, but I prefer to keep it light.

Comment: Upvoted. As for the last part, I finally figured out how to get the same functionality without the (unused) buffer. See my answer below if interested.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a solution that renders the questions about memory irrelevant (although I'm still curious).

> if I want to use the callback but *not* the `body` (because you can still  `pipe`), will this memory buffer still be filled?

You don't need the `callback` from `request()` in order to know when the request is finished. The `pipe()` will close itself when the `stream` 'ends'. The close emits an event and can be listened for:

```
request(url).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename)).on('close', function(){           
    next();
});
```

Now you can queue all your requests and download files one by one.

Of course you can vacuum the internet using 8 parallel requests all the time with libraries such as [`async.queue`](https://github.com/caolan/async#queue), but if all you want to do is get some files with a simple script, `async` is probably overkill.

Besides, you're not gonna want to max out your system resources for a single trick on a multi-user system anyway.